# How can I find which role my fabfile is executing under in a task?

Tags: fabric

In the command line I do:

```
fab task -Rproduction
```

Is there a hook that lets me find out what role I'm executing under in the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "not until 2.0" 
https://github.com/fabric/fabric/pull/824